# Phaza Point save over other attributes when save() is called on new model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1 and the `Phaza\LaravelPostgis\Geometries\Point` class in a controller.
When I save a new `Ride` model with the Point object as an attribute it sometimes overwrites other attributes in the model in Laravel.
If you check the Database, the data is persisted correctly but the saved model has the incorrect attributes when being used further in the controller.

The model definition is as follows

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Phaza\LaravelPostgis\Geometries\Point;
use Phaza\LaravelPostgis\Eloquent\PostgisTrait;

class Ride extends Model
{
    use PostgisTrait;

    /**
     * Define which properties are postgis types
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $postgisFields = ['start_location' => Point::class, 'end_location' => Point::class];

}
```

The model is assigned to like this

```
    $newRide = new Ride();

    $newRide->start_location = new Point($request->start_latitude, $request->start_longitude);
    $newRide->end_location = new Point($request->end_latitude, $request->end_longitude);

    if (isset($request->vehicle)) {
        $newVehicle = new Vehicle();
        $newVehicle->make = isset($request->vehicle['make']) ? $request->vehicle['make'] : '';
        $newVehicle->model = isset($request->vehicle['model']) ? $request->vehicle['model'] : '';
        $newVehicle->registration = isset($request->vehicle['registration']) ? $request->vehicle['registration'] : '';
        $newVehicle->additional = isset($request->vehicle['additional']) ? $request->vehicle['additional'] : '';
        $newVehicle->reference = isset($request->vehicle['reference']) ? $request->vehicle['reference'] : '';
        $newVehicle->save();

        $newRide->vehicle_id = $newVehicle->id;
    }


    $newRide->save();
```

The Model object looks like this before the save

```
{
    "ride": {
        "start_location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                28.276439,
                -25.780843
            ]
        },
        "end_location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                28.276439,
                -25.980843
            ]
        },
        "vehicle_id": 6
    }
}
```

The Model object looks like this after the save

```
{
    "ride": {
        "start_location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                28.276439,
                -25.780843
            ]
        },
        "end_location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                28.276439,
                -25.980843
            ]
        },
        "vehicle_id": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                28.276439,
                -25.980843
            ]
        },
        "updated_at": "2019-11-21 14:10:51",
        "created_at": "2019-11-21 14:10:51",
        "id": 4
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I move the assignment of the 2 points to just before the save() I do get the correct output. Can someone please help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show your entire code of saving, from here `$newRide = new Ride();` to here `$newRide->save();`.

Comment: I have come across this a few times now and it seems that it happens when I create a new model. I have to then run `$model = $model->fresh()` for it fix it's fields